# Can we get post on friends wall and comments, likes on those posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, windows-phone-7.1, facebook-fql

Can we get `relationship status changes` of our friends from last 3 days including present day

`what my app requires is the data of the friends who recently engaged/married etc`

AND

`Anniversary details` from last 3 days to next 15 days (may be this can be done by reading the  friends posts on our wall with `happy anniversary` etc but how to get the friends wall post data posted by others using facebook api

and `status updates` of last 3 days including present day and `comments` and likes on those status updates

`Graph API` or `FQL` both are fine

I am using facebook c# sdk for my windows phone app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you must have some pretty … *interesting* … friends, if you’re interested in their relationship status changes for intervals of *three* days – or are you trying to build an app for finding rebound s*x partners …? ;-)

Well, as all of the user fields (except *verified*) are available for *real time updates*, that could be one way for you to get notified of such changes (and then put their “history” into your own database).

Comment: I did not understand your answer properly, but what i need is my app requires the data of the friends who recently engaged/married etc

Comment: Real time updates are described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/

Comment: is there any other way? because we don't want to cache the data. Can we get friends wallposts data posted by others?